# Spring boot loading log4j2.xml with different Name log4j2-app.xml

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have a requirement to deploy two different spring boot application in one weblogic server, we are using one log4j2.xml in both applications which is copied in the class path. Now i want to separate the log4j2.xml for each application. I tried by giving this property logging.config=log4j2-app1.xml in application.properties file, but its not working. Please suggest how to handle this suituation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to provide the right resource prefix. If `log4j2-app1.xml` lives in your classpath, you should probably use:

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-app1.xml
```

If it's an external file, you could use:

```
logging.config=file:log4j2-app1.xml
```

Comment: I tried with this approach but its not working, if i place log4j2.xml in the classpath its working but if i rename to log4j2-app1.xml logs not getting generated